# Get mp3 length in C++

Tags: c++, mp3, fileinfo

So, I have some (big) song list in plain text. I wrote a parser that creates a list of structures containing artist, title and length of the songs. I also have a huge folder of mp3s that are corresponding to my list, but randomly named, (e.g. 1b942ca9231291.mp3).
What I want is to create a list of lengths and filenames from the folder, so that I can rename the files according to length equivalence, prompting user when collisions occur.
I'd like to do all this without using ID3-oriented libraries, please do not suggest them.

Comment: Check [this link](http://mpgedit.org/mpgedit/mpeg_format/MP3Format.html). It contains a description of the mp3 format, but it's tough though.

Comment: @MichaelWalz As you (can?) see, this link was already provided in answer by the swine. Anyways, thanks for trying to help.

Comment: I can't understand what's unclear in my question. I actually asked for a way to get mp3 length w/o involving ID3 Tags and corresponding libraries. I think I stated that clearly enough, if not, suggest how should I edit my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fortunately for you, it is quite simple to parse the MP3 format. You do not need to decode it, just look at the [header](http://www.mpgedit.org/mpgedit/mpeg_format/MP3Format.html). The MP3 does not have a single header like most files, instead a single file is split to many frames (packets) with their own headers which can be spotted without needing to know their exact location and with the possibility to interleave them with some other data (sometimes referred to as sideband info, it is usually ID3 tags, but it can be pretty much anything). That is why MP3 is good for streaming music, so anyone can connect to the middle of the stream and start playback (the same thing works if you split the MP3 file to two halves, both first and second file will play without problems, something that e.g. WAV or PNG format will not support).

You need to figure out the bitrate in `kBps` and to count the size of the frames (the structures associated with each header) and just divide them up. For CBR files you can get a reasonable estimate by just dividing the whole file size, which is much faster. It helps to ignore ID3 tags, especially if they contain bulky album art images.

You can check out my old [music checker](http://www.stud.fit.vutbr.cz/~xpolok00/proj/MusicChecker_2011-08-29_closed-dev_.zip) program which decodes the MP3 headers and checks for damage. You will need an old version (not sure which one) of this [framework](http://www.stud.fit.vutbr.cz/~xpolok00/proj_uberlame.htm) to build it.

Comment: Thanks for link to header help file. I don't think I will dig deep into your old project, maybe just take the bitrate extractor if I find one. So basically 1 frame = 1 second, then after division I just have to convert seconds to MM:SS?

Comment: No, e.g. `128 kBps` frame takes `128 kB` to store `1 second`. So divide size (of the whole file / or better of the useful audio data in it) by `128 kB` to get playtime in seconds. Things get more complicated with VBR as there each frame can have a different bitrate (different `kBps` for each frame). In `MP3.cpp` you can find all frame parsing and ID3 parsing routines you need for the job.

Comment: Would have been better to put the code here. You link is broken.

Comment: @TheRealChx101 Thanks, they must have deleted my old student page. Will upload it elsewhere. "Putting the code here" is not appropriate as it is thousands of lines.